# How to run xdg-open to execute a google search from command line?

Tags: linux, bash, automation, xdgutils

If I can search google from the command line on Ubuntu, it would save me a lot of time in my workflow. If I run this it opens up Google.

```
xdg-open 'https://www.google.com/search?q="searchterm1" "searchterm2"'
```

I dont know how to make this google.sh accept inputs though.

**Essentially I want to run this in the command line**

```
./googler.sh searchterm1 searchterm2 searchterm3
```

This will open this Google link in the browser

```
https://www.google.com/search?q= "searchterm1" "searchterm2" "searchterm3"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to accept an arbitrary number of arguments, you can do something like this:

```
#!/bin/sh

quote_search_terms() {
    for term in "$@"; do
        echo "\"$term\" "
    done
}

xdg-open "https://www.google.com/search?q=$(quote_search_terms "$@")"
```

This will give you behavior similar to what you've shown in your question.

Comment: Would it be easy to add another site to this  - like https://www.bing.com/search?q=searchterm1

This could be really useful if I can open many search windows from the terminal

Comment: Nice!!!

xdg-open "https://www.google.com/search?q=$(quote_search_terms "$@")";xdg-open "https://bing.com/search?q=$(quote_search_terms "$@")"